# jade ghost property

Tags: node.js, pug

The template:

```
p= user
```

Outputs:

```
<p>{ admin: "true", human: "Foo Bar" }</p>
```

(among some other stuff that usually isn't seen by the the user but is used to render different parts of the layout (or not) depending on various factors)

The template:

```
p= user.human
```

Outputs:

```
<p>Foo Bar</p>
```

As expected so far.  However, the template:

```
p= user.admin
```

Outputs:

```
<p></p>
```

I have no idea how this is even possible.  The property is there when I output the entire object, but it disappears when I try to output just that property.

I've also tried using `user['admin']` instead of `user.admin`, but that doesn't work either.

First question: how is this happening?
Second question: how do I fix it?

**Update 1:** The pattern `p #{user.admin}` has the same effect, and `p= user.admin.toString()` results in a 500 error claiming `'user.admin' is not defined`.  Furthermore, `JSON.stringify(user.admin)` also results in the empty p tag (as in `p= user.admin` and `p #{user.admin}`)

**Update 2:** `p= JSON.stringify(user)` *does* output the 'admin' property: `{"admin":"true","human":"Foo Bar"}` but iterating over `user` with `each value,key in user` does *not* output the 'admin' property.  The output is extremely long in that case as it includes a bunch of functions and other things, but I used ctrl+f to search through the output and could not find 'admin'.

Comment: Can you post JSON.stringify(user) output?

Comment: Can you access the variable in the Javascript code which passes this object to jade?

Comment: @dave: no, console.log(req.user.admin) logs 'undefined' on the server side; but then how is JSON.stringify(user) and just plain old `p= user` able to access it?

Comment: I don't have the slightest clue … I guess you broke Jade :-)

Comment: on a side-note, console.log(req.user) *does* output the 'admin' field, bizarrely, so it's not just Jade that can see it - node.js can see it until it's accessed directly too (suggesting that the problem lies with node.js and not jade)

Comment: Did you add the `admin` property to the `user` object yourself or was this done via a script from someone else? If you added it yourself, how exactly did you do so?

Comment: The `user` object is actually retrieved from a mongodb backend using the `passport` library, and `admin` is a custom property I added to schema myself.  I set up the first user manually using the `mongo` command-line interface.  I... think I might know what's wrong now, because the Schema specifies that 'admin' is a 'boolean', but it's actually stored as a string... I'm going to try changing that to 'string' and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's what was wrong:

I was retrieving a Mongoose object that had the 'admin' property set, but the Schema didn't actually specify the 'admin' property at all.  I'm unsure exactly how Jade was picking it up, but Mongoose was obviously highly confused about what the 'admin' property was and what to do with it.

The solution was to simply add 'admin': 'string' to my mongoose.Schema object.

Thanks to dave and King Julian for both of your help.  I've upvoted your two answers since they did help me reach this conclusion (as well as your comments, but you don't get rep for those I'm afraid!).

Answer (score 1):

This might be because the value for admin is interpreted as a boolean. Some things to try:

```
p #{user.admin}
```

or

```
p= user.admin.toString()
```

Comment: The former has the same effect as p= user.admin, the latter results in a 500 error because 'user.admin' is 'not defined'.  Thanks for your input though, I'm truly baffled here.

Comment: There is no user.admin then.

Comment: With all due respect, it is output by JSON.stringify and `p= user`, so it must exist in some sense.  It's also definitely set in the mongodb database, since I set it manually and verified that it was set afterwards.  So it does exist in some form.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```
each value, key in user
    p #{value} [#{key}]
```

Does "admin" get outputed?